# Unity - The same field name is serialized multiple times in the class or its parent class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have an abstract class from which i derive the various classes i use for the UI, i have a virtual method that i override, but unity shows me this warning when i go to compile (The same field name is serialized multiple times in the class or its parent class), if i declare the isActive variable as protected and i remove the variable isActive from the inherited class this does not happen.

I'm a beginner, the question is more like this, am i implementing this thing the wrong way or is it correct to use isActive as protected?

Base class

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(CanvasGroup))]
public abstract class UserInterface : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector] public CanvasGroup _canvasGroup;

    private bool _isActive;
    public virtual void SetActive(bool active)
    {
        if(_isActive == active) return;

        _isActive = active;
        _canvasGroup.alpha = active ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
        _canvasGroup.interactable = active;
        _canvasGroup.blocksRaycasts = active;
    }
}
```

Inherited class

```
    private bool _isActive;
    public override void SetActive(bool active)
    {
        if (_isActive == active) return;

        _isActive = active;
        _messageAnimator.Play(active ? "Message In" : "Message Out");
        _canvasGroup.interactable = active;
        _canvasGroup.blocksRaycasts = active;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you reuse so big chunks of code between parent/child class you are doing something wrong (or maybe you need interface if you expect it might have totally different implementations?). Anyway, try leaving setting _isActive logic to parent class and let child classes just handle state change accordingly like that:

```
public class UserInterface : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector] public CanvasGroup _canvasGroup;
    private bool _isActive;

    public void SetActive(bool active)
    {
        if(_isActive == active) return;

        _isActive = active;
        HandleActiveChanged(_isActive);        
    }

    protected virtual void HandleActiveChanged(bool active)
    {
        _canvasGroup.alpha = active ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
        _canvasGroup.interactable = active;
        _canvasGroup.blocksRaycasts = active;
    }
}
```

And then the other class just need to override HandleActiveChanged

```
public class ChildUserInterface : UserInteraface
{
    protected override void HandleActiveChanged(bool active)
    {
        _messageAnimator.Play(active ? "Message In" : "Message Out");
        _canvasGroup.interactable = active;
        _canvasGroup.blocksRaycasts = active;
    }
}
```

Or else you need to change name of _isActive, this is not C# issue, you should be able to reuse private field names, this is Unity serialization thing.

The approach with interfaces would look like this:

You create interface:

```
public interface IUserInteraface
{
    void SetActive(bool isActive);
}
```

and then both of your classes inherit from both MonoBehaviour and IUserInterface

```
public class UserInterface : MonoBehaviour, IUserInterface
{
    void IUserInterface.SetActive(bool active)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class SecondUserInterface : MonoBehaviour, IUserInterface
{
    void IUserInterface.SetActive(bool active)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

and you then need implemented SetActive independently in both classes like you already did in your code.

Comment: might even make sense to split it up and move the two lines `_canvasGroup.interactable = active;  _canvasGroup.blocksRaycasts = active;` at the end of `SetActive` then you (OP) wouldn't have to re-write them every time and rather only implement the thing that is actually different

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I prefer to use the first method, I have various inherited classes that do not override, after all I would have to rewrite the code many times even using interfaces or not?

Comment: Yes. The Interface approach forces you to have implementation each time you implement that interface, but you can still create Base Class implementing that interface and override it to reuse code.

So you would have
UserInterface : MonoBehaviour, IUserInterface and SecondUserInterface : UserInterface, and then you can create new UI either implementing "IUserInterface" or inheriting from "UserInterface", depending if you want to reuse that code